# R stacked percentage bar plot with percentage of binary factor and labels (with ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to produce a graphic that looks something like this:

[image]

My original data set looks something like this:

```
> bb[sample(nrow(bb), 20), ]
      IMG QUANT FIX
25663   1     1   0
7936    2     2   0
23586   3     2   0
23017   2     2   1
31363   1     3   1
7886    2     2   0
23819   3     3   1
29838   2     2   1
8169    2     3   1
9870    2     3   0
31440   2     1   0
35564   3     1   0
24066   1     2   0
12020   3     2   0
6742    3     2   0
6189    2     3   0
26692   2     3   0
1387    3     2   0
31839   2     3   1
28637   3     2   0
```

So the idea is that the bars display where `FIX = 1` per factor `QUANT` and per
factor `IMG`.

I've aggregated my data set into percentages using `plyr`

```
library(plyr)
bb.perc <- ddply(bb,.(QUANT,IMG),summarise,FIX.PROP = sum(FIX) / length(FIX))
```

It does *almost* the right thing:

```
  QUANT IMG   FIX.PROP
1     1   1 0.52439024
2     1   2 0.19085366
3     1   3 0.13658537
4     2   1 0.20414201
5     2   2 0.53964497
6     2   3 0.09585799
7     3   1 0.29000000
8     3   2 0.13000000
9     3   3 0.40705882
```

But now if I make a graph, it doesn't account for the `FIX==0` cases, i.e. all bars have the same height, namely 100%, which isn't what I want. Note how the individual QUANT subframes don't add up to 100%:

```
> sum(bb.perc[1:3,]$FIX.PROP)
[1] 0.8518293
> sum(bb.perc[4:6,]$FIX.PROP)
[1] 0.839645
> sum(bb.perc[7:9,]$FIX.PROP)
[1] 0.8270588
```

The best I could do with R is to display counts:

```
# Take only the positive samples
bb.pos <- bb[bb$FIX == 1,]
# Plot the counts
ggplot(bb,aes(factor(QUANT),fill=factor(IMG))) + geom_bar() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

And results in:
[image]
This is also not what I want:

- The percentage scale is way off. I need a way to pass the 100% point to the
  `percent` function, but I have no idea how.
- It lacks the labels.

There are a great deal of *similar* questions on SO already, but I seem to lack
the sufficient amount of intelligence (or understanding of R) to extrapolate
from them to a solution to my particular problem.

Thanks for any pointers!

EDIT: Sven Hohenstein provided an answer already, but here's how I ended up doing it myself as well:

```
> ggplot(bb.perc,aes(x=factor(QUANT),y=FIX.PROP,label=paste(round(FIX.PROP*100),
     "%"),fill=factor(IMG)))+ geom_bar(stat="identity") + geom_text(position="stack",
     aes(ymax=1),vjust=5) + scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

Using the `bb.perc` that I defined further up using `plyr`. This one has the
advantage that the percentages are computed locally per column, and not
globally.

Thanks everyone for the help. The following two questions and their respective
answers helped me greatly in getting it right:

[Stacked Bar Graph Labels with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243621/stacked-bar-graph-labels-with-ggplot2)

[Adding labels to ggplot bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653268/adding-labels-to-ggplot-bar-chart)

What I did wrong initially, was pass the `position = "fill"` parameter to
`geom_bar()`, which for some reason made all the bars have the same height!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a way to generate the plot:

```
ggplot(bb[bb$FIX == 1, ],aes(x = factor(QUANT), fill = factor(IMG), 
                             y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
 geom_bar() +
 stat_bin(geom = "text",
          aes(label = paste(round((..count..)/sum(..count..)*100), "%")),
          vjust = 5) +
 scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

Change the value of the `vjust` parameter to adjust the vertical position of the labels.

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thanks! I actually had just right now gotten to the point where I had the correct plot as well, but I was using the `plyr` way to do it. I didn't know it was possible from within ggplot itself!