# ggplot stacked bar chart with counts on y axis but percentage as label

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a problem connected with one once discussed. This example [R: ggplot stacked bar chart with counts on y axis but percentage as label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817809/r-ggplot-stacked-bar-chart-with-counts-on-y-axis-but-percentage-as-label) I used few months ago  to generate this kind of plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 7, ncol= 3,
                   data = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5", "ID6", "ID7",
                            "north", "north", "north", "north", "south", "south", "south",
                            "A", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A", "C"),
                  byrow = FALSE))




colnames(df) <- c("ID", "region", "species")


ggplot(df %>% count(region, species) %>%    # Group by region and species, then count number in each group
     mutate(pct=n/sum(n)),              # Calculate percent within each region
   aes(region, n, fill=species)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0(sprintf("%1.1f", pct*100),"%")), 
        position=position_stack(vjust=0.5))
```

Everything worked well. But now if i run the same code, i get a plot like this:

[Myplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDKot.jpg)

Have anybody had similar problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not knowing any context, what *is* your question/problem?

Comment: Note to add `group_by(region)` to get the desired output. Until now you will have the overall percentage and not the percentage per region. `df %>% group_by(region) %>% count(region, species) %>%    # Group by region and species, then count number in each group
         mutate(pct=n/sum(n)`
if you read the comments exactly, you see the group_by command ... but it was missed in the code

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped! But I can't understand why the same code (without group_by) worked well few months ago. Can it be possible that I had some ohter version/ ohter package in addition so the group_by wasn't neccesary?! I've tried very many ways to detect the reason, but without results...