# ggplot dimension on x asis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have following dataframe:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
Y     N    N    N
Y     N    Y    Y
Y     N    N    Y
Y     N    N    N
```

I would like to use ggplot to plot a chart with %values written in bar itself.

[image]

Comment: Reshape your data - *melt*, then *geom_bar*, then see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695497/show-instead-of-counts-in-charts-of-categorical-variables). Show some effort. Possible duplicate.

Comment: Perhaps you can show us what you have tried, and why it has failed. Then this will read more like a question and less like an order to a contractor.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386005/r-stacked-percentage-bar-plot-with-percentage-of-binary-factor-and-labels-with) would also help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do just fine

```
#your data.frame
df <- read.table(text=
                "col1 col2 col3 col4
                 Y     N    N    N
                 Y     N    Y    Y
                 Y     N    N    Y
                 Y     N    N    N", header=T)
library(reshape2)
df$ID <- 1:length(df)
df <- melt(df, id.vars = "ID") #melting the data.frame into long format
library(ggplot2) #and ploting it
ggplot(df)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=variable, fill=value), stat="count")
```

For an outcome in percentages you can do

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=variable, y= (..count..)/sum(..count..), fill=value))
```