# plot value labels along with bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Showing data values on stacked bar chart in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644997/showing-data-values-on-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2)

I have the following ggplot

[image]

```
dt <- structure(list(Age.group = structure(1:5, .Label = c("0-29 yrs", "30-49 yrs", "50-64 yrs", "65-79 yrs", "80+ years"), class = "factor"),     Rx.Brufen = c(4.91767279891635, 24.849329416471, 39.384529665324,     42.0512030516413, 45.0282816501013), Brufen.C.I = c(9.49857407873833,     10.4942035949849, 11.0935906177108, 16.7322917304551, 18.5232702433842   ), Brufen.declined = c(1.25219908256281, 1.1156980249761,     1.18510539437499, 0.73845826559561, 1.00121613129538)), .Names = c("Age.group", "Rx.Brufen", "Brufen.C.I", "Brufen.declined"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

dt.m <- melt(dt, 1)

colnames(dt.m)[2] <- "Rx"
colnames(dt.m)[3] <- "Proportion"
ggplot(dt.m, aes(x=Age.group,y=Proportion, fill=Rx)) +
    geom_bar() +
    labs(x="Age Group", y="Proportion %",fill = "") +
    theme(legend.position=c(.5, .9), legend.direction = "horizontal" ) +
    ylim(c(0,100))
```

I would like to plot the actual values, as percentages (inside the bars for the green and red bars,  and just above for the blue ones, since they won't fit inside). Can someone advise how to achieve this ?

Comment: Are you sure about function theme()?

Comment: @AliSharifi , sorry, I didn't understand your question. Sure about what ? theme() is positioning the legend I think........?

Answer (score 3):

```
p <-  ggplot(dt.m, aes(x=Age.group,y=Proportion, fill=Rx)) +
geom_bar() +
labs(x="Age Group", y="Proportion %",fill = "") +
theme(legend.position=c(.5, .9), legend.direction = "horizontal" ) +
ylim(c(0,100))

library(plyr)
dt.m.text <- ddply(dt.m, .variables="Age.group", transform, text.y=cumsum(Proportion))
p+geom_text(data=dt.m.text, aes(x = Age.group, y = text.y, label = round(Proportion)))
#close

dt.m.text <- ddply(dt.m, .variables="Age.group", transform, text.y = cumsum(Proportion)-1/2*Proportion)
p+geom_text(data=dt.m.text, aes(x=Age.group,y=text.y, label=round(Proportion)))

#manually increase Brufen.declined
up <-  dt.m.text[dt.m.text$Rx=="Brufen.declined","text.y"]
dt.m.text[dt.m.text$Rx=="Brufen.declined","text.y"] <- up + 1
p+geom_text(data=dt.m.text, aes(x=Age.group,y=text.y, label=round(Proportion)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this one after you have defined your data `dt` to find the label positions - as you need:

```
p=dt
p[,4]=p[,4]+p[,3]+p[,2]
p[,3]=p[,3]/2+p[,2]
p[,2]=p[,2]/2
p.m = melt(p)
colnames(p.m)[2:3]=c("Rx","Proportion")
```

And add this part to your `ggplot` command:

```
+ geom_text(aes(Age.group, `Proportion`, label = sprintf("%2.1f", `Proportion`)), data=p.m)
```