# Stacked bar chart values are overlapping.How to show them correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

In bar chart values are appearing incorrectly.How to correct it.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Demand_Supply,fill=time_slot),position = 'stack') +  
       geom_bar()  +  facet_wrap(~`Pickup.point`) + 
       geom_text(stat='count',aes(label=abs(..count..)))
```

Comment: This is a duplicate- see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39269895/labels-overlapping-on-stacked-bar-chart-ggplot2

Answer (score 0):

You can control it using vjust and hjust.

Try following:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Demand_Supply,fill=time_slot),position = 'stack')+ geom_bar() + facet_wrap(~Pickup.point)+
geom_text(stat='count',aes(label=abs(..count..)), , vjust = -0.5)
```

you can try different permutation and combination with hjust and vjust.

Comment: ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Demand_Supply,fill=time_slot),position = 'stack') +  geom_bar()  +  facet_wrap(~`Pickup.point`) + 
  geom_text(stat='count',aes(label=abs(..count..)),size = 3, hjust = 0.5, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))

Comment: It got correct.

Comment: @chandrapalpanwarplease accept it as answer or upvote if it deserves.