# Creating a stacked bar chart with counts printed in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

So i want to create a stacked bar chart, with frequency counts printed for each
fill factor.

[Showing data values on stacked bar chart in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644997/showing-data-values-on-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2)

This question places the counts in the center of each segment, but the user specifies the values. In this example we dont input the specific value, and I am seeking an r function that automatically calcualtes counts.

Take the following data for example.

```
set.seed(123)
a <- sample(1:4, 50, replace = TRUE)
b <- sample(1:10, 50, replace = TRUE)
data <- data.frame(a,b)
data$c <- cut(data$b, breaks = c(0,3,6,10), right = TRUE,
                         labels = c ("M", "N", "O"))
head(data)

ggplot(data, aes(x = a, fill = c)) + geom_bar(position="fill")
```

So I want to print a "n= .." for M,N and O value in 1,2,3 and 4

So the end result looks like

[image]

Similiar to this question, however we do not have fr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
obj <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]

# some tricks for getting centered the y-positions:
library(dplyr)
y_cen <- obj[["y"]]
y_cen[is.na(y_cen)] <- 0
y_cen <- (y_cen - lag(y_cen))/2 + lag(y_cen)
y_cen[y_cen == 0 | y_cen == .5] <- NA

p + annotate("text", x = obj[["x"]], y = y_cen, label = paste("N = ", obj[["count"]]))
```

Which gives:

[image]