# Count and Percent Together using Stack Bar in R

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, stat

I am trying to create stack bar with counts and percent in same graph. I took help from [Showing data values on stacked bar chart in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644997/showing-data-values-on-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2) and add group total and plotted my as [image: on this image]

```
By using code 

### to plot stacked bar graph with total on the top and
###    distribution of the frequency;

library(ggplot2);
library(plyr);
library(dplyr);

Year      <- c(rep(c("2006-07", "2007-08", "2008-09", "2009-10"), each = 4))
Category  <- c(rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), times = 4))
Frequency <- c(168, 259, 226, 340, 216, 431, 319, 368, 423, 645, 234, 685, 166, 467, 274, 251)
Data      <- data.frame(Year, Category, Frequency);


sum_count <- 
   Data %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  summarise(max_pos = sum(Frequency));

sum_count;


Data <- ddply(Data, .(Year), transform, pos = 
cumsum(Frequency) - (0.5 * Frequency));

Data;



# plot bars and add text
p <- ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency)) +
     geom_bar(aes(fill = Category), stat="identity") +
     geom_text(aes(label=Frequency,y = pos), size = 3) +  
     geom_text(data = sum_count, 
     aes(y = max_pos, label = max_pos), size = 4,
     vjust = -0.5);

print(p);
```

/*Now I want to overlay percent of each group with counts This is my         approach.merge data such a way that we can calculate
% for each of the group you are dealing with*/

```
    MergeData <- merge(Data,sum_count,by="Year");

    MergeData <- transform(MergeData,
    per_cent=round((pos/max_pos)*100,0));
    MergeData<- ddply(MergeData, .(Year), transform, per_pos = 
    cumsum(per_cent) - (0.5 * per_cent));

    # calculate percent and attach % sign;

    MergeData <- transform(MergeData,
    per_cent=paste(round((pos/max_pos)*100,0),"%"));

    # Data only with percents

    Percent_Data <- subset(MergeData,select 
    = c("Year","Category","per_cent","per_pos"));
```

/*I am wondering if it is possible to overlay percent data to the image I created using previous code so that number and percent can be presented together.*/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are almost there. 
Use `MergeData` as the source for the data frame and add one more call to `geom_text`

```
p <- ggplot(MergeData, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency, group = Category)) +
 geom_bar(aes(fill = Category), stat="identity") +
 geom_text(aes(label=Frequency,y = pos), size = 3, vjust = 1) +  
 geom_text(
        aes(y = max_pos, label = max_pos), size = 4,
        vjust = -.5) + 
 geom_text(aes(x = Year, y = pos, label = per_cent), vjust = -1, size = 4)

  print(p);
```

You may need to fiddle with `hjust` and `vjust` to get the text just how you like it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response. I think it is very good.

```
p <- ggplot(MergeData, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency, group = Category)) +
     geom_bar(aes(fill = Category), stat="identity") +
     geom_text(aes(label=Frequency,y = pos),  vjust = 1,size = 2,hjust = 0.5) +  
     geom_text(aes(y = max_pos, label = max_pos), size = 3,vjust = -.1) + 
     geom_text(aes(x = Year, y = pos, label = per_cent), vjust = -.4, size = 2)+
     xlab("Year") + ylab(" Number of People") +            # Set axis labels
     ggtitle("Distribution by Category over Year") +  # Set title
     theme(panel.background = 
     element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'white'),
     legend.position = "bottom" ,
     legend.title = element_text(color="black",
     size=7),
     legend.key.width = unit(1,"inch") );

 print(p);
```

now my % on top of number numbers,in other words, it is "17%" and "168" but I want "168" and "17%". I tried switching position of geom_text() but it did not work. I am wondering if you know how to fix it.

Comment: Use the `vjust` argument in `geom_text`. Above swapping the two `vjust` arguments should do it

Answer (score 0):

Yes it helped. I fixed number to make center of each stack. therefore i  needed to make change in percent below code fixed my issue. Thank you so much for your help.

```
p <- ggplot(MergeData, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency, group = Category)) +
     geom_bar(aes(fill = Category), stat="identity") +
     geom_text(aes(label=Frequency,y = pos),  vjust = 1,
     size = 2,hjust = 0.5) +  
     geom_text(aes(y = max_pos, label = max_pos), size = 3,vjust = -.1) + 
     geom_text(aes(x = Year, y = pos, label = per_cent), vjust = 1.95, 
     size = 2,hjust=0.3)+
     xlab("Year") + ylab(" Number of People") +            # Set axis labels
     ggtitle("Distribution by Category over Year") +       # Set title;
      theme(panel.background = 
    element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'white'),
    legend.position = "bottom" ,
    legend.title = element_text(color="black",
    size=7) );
 print(p);
```