# create stack bar with counts and fill/group levels in the same graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create stack bar with counts and Group levels in the same graph (inside of plot). since the group variable has 25 levels, I prefer to bring the name of group levels inside of plot (since we have 25 different colour and is difficult for visualization).I took help from "[Showing data values on stacked bar chart in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644997/showing-data-values-on-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2)". I was wondering how can I add the name of each group level inside of graph.

```
Year      <- c(rep(c("2006-07", "2007-08", "2008-09", "2009-10"), each = 4))
Category  <- c(rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), times = 4))
Frequency <- c(168, 259, 226, 340, 216, 431, 319, 368, 423, 645, 234, 685, 166, 467, 274, 251)
Data      <- data.frame(Year, Category, Frequency)

library(dplyr)  
Data <- group_by(Data,Year) %>%
 mutate(pos = cumsum(Frequency) - (0.5 * Frequency))

library(ggplot2)
#plot bars and add text
p <- ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency)) +
     geom_bar(aes(fill = Category), stat="identity") +
     geom_text(aes(label = Frequency, y = pos), size = 3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines would do the trick:

```
p <- ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Category), stat="identity", show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Frequency, y = pos), size = 3, nudge_y = -25) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Category, y = pos), size = 3, nudge_y = 25)
```

which plots

[image: plot with labels on stacked bars]

Customize as you like.

Comment: Hi, Could you please give me an advice regarding reordering these cells based on their frequencies.

Comment: Put `arrange(desc(Frequency))` (for smallest bars at the top; remove `desc` for the reverse) in your `dplyr` chain *before the `mutate`*.