# Adding text in stacked bar where levels are ordered using stat=summary

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

Here is the data:

```
df_test<-structure(list(MIRNA = c("let-7c", "let-7c", "let-7c", "let-7c", 
"let-7c", "let-7c", "let-7c", "mir-125b-2", "mir-125b-2", "mir-125b-2", 
"mir-125b-2", "mir-125b-2", "mir-125b-2", "mir-125b-2", "mir-155", 
"mir-155", "mir-155", "mir-155", "mir-155", "mir-155", "mir-155", 
"mir-4760", "mir-4760", "mir-4760", "mir-4760", "mir-4760", "mir-4760", 
"mir-4760", "mir-548x", "mir-548x", "mir-548x", "mir-548x", "mir-548x", 
"mir-548x", "mir-6501", "mir-6501", "mir-6501", "mir-6501", "mir-6501", 
"mir-6501", "mir-6501", "mir-6508", "mir-6508", "mir-6508", "mir-6508", 
"mir-6508", "mir-6508", "mir-6508", "mir-6814", "mir-6814", "mir-6814", 
"mir-6814", "mir-6814", "mir-6814", "mir-6815", "mir-6815", "mir-6815", 
"mir-6815", "mir-6815", "mir-6815", "mir-99a", "mir-99a", "mir-99a", 
"mir-99a", "mir-99a", "mir-99a", "mir-99a"), MIRNA_Feature = structure(c(6L, 
5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 
2L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 
1L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 
5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 
1L, 4L), .Label = c("Precursor_5PrimeEnd", "5p_Seed", "5p_Mature", 
"Precursor_Loop", "3p_Seed", "3p_Mature", "Precursor_3PrimeEnd"
), class = "factor"), domain_length = c(13L, 9L, 13L, 9L, 7L, 
10L, 23L, 13L, 9L, 13L, 9L, 14L, 16L, 15L, 13L, 9L, 14L, 9L, 
1L, 3L, 16L, 13L, 9L, 13L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 20L, 14L, 9L, 11L, 9L, 
10L, 45L, 14L, 9L, 13L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 19L, 13L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 2L, 
4L, 11L, 13L, 9L, 13L, 9L, 5L, 21L, 12L, 9L, 14L, 9L, 5L, 12L, 
13L, 9L, 13L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 15L), order = c(6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 
1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 
6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 
2L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 4L), expr = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2.6, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3.4, 1, 1, 3.6, 2.6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2.4, 1, 1, 6, 3.4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2.4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2.8, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.6)), .Names = c("MIRNA", "MIRNA_Feature", 
"domain_length", "order", "expr"), row.names = c("29", "30", 
"31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "334", "335", "336", "337", "338", 
"339", "340", "695", "696", "697", "698", "699", "700", "701", 
"3084", "3085", "3086", "3087", "3088", "3089", "3090", "4111", 
"4112", "4113", "4114", "4115", "4116", "4433", "4434", "4435", 
"4436", "4437", "4438", "4439", "4481", "4482", "4483", "4484", 
"4485", "4486", "4487", "5260", "5261", "5262", "5263", "5264", 
"5265", "5266", "5267", "5268", "5269", "5270", "5271", "6098", 
"6099", "6100", "6101", "6102", "6103", "6104"), class = "data.frame")
```

I order them according to the levels in the MIRNA_Feature column like so:

```
df_test$MIRNA_Feature<-factor(df_test$MIRNA_Feature,levels=c("Precursor_5PrimeEnd","5p_Seed","5p_Mature","Precursor_Loop","3p_Seed","3p_Mature","Precursor_3PrimeEnd"))
```

Then plot the stacked bargraph with labels and get this plot:

```
ggplot(df_test,aes(x=MIRNA,y=domain_length,fill = MIRNA_Feature))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+geom_label(aes(label=expr),position="stack")+coord_flip()
```

[image]

The problem is the order that I specified got lost.I could obtain the desired order using stat=summary like so but then the order of the labels are all off:

```
ggplot(df_test,aes(x=MIRNA,y=domain_length,fill = MIRNA_Feature))+geom_bar(stat="summary",fun.y=sum)+geom_label(aes(label=expr),position="stack")+coord_flip()
```

The plot looks like this: 
[image]

Looks like the ordering of the labels are done separately (alphabetically) and the stacks are done according to the specified order when using stat="summary". Any help in resolving this is much appreciated.

Comment: Change `df_test$MIRNA_Feature<-factor(as.factor(df_test$MIRNA_Feature),...` to `df_test$MIRNA_Feature<-factor(df_test$MIRNA_Feature,...`

Comment: @eipi10 yep...agreed..that's unnecessary. I will fix it. Also thanks for centering the labels ...this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644997/showing-data-values-on-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2#comment7870900_6644997)  + ggplot2 geom_text page was helpful as well. Didn't want to bug with order + position at once. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [ggplot version 2.1, `stat_summary`](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md) preserves the order in the data frame, so you need to sort the values beforehand. For example:

```
ggplot(df_test[order(df_test$MIRNA, df_test$MIRNA_Feature),],
       aes(x=MIRNA,y=domain_length,fill = MIRNA_Feature)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="summary", fun.y=sum) +
  geom_label(aes(label=expr), position="stack") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Centering the labels within each bar would make the plot a bit less confusing. You can do this by creating a new column (which I've called `y.pos`) to set the label position. I've used the chaining operator (`%>%`) from the `dplyr` package to streamline this:

```
library(dplyr)

df_test %>% 
  group_by(MIRNA) %>% 
  arrange(MIRNA, MIRNA_Feature) %>%
  mutate(y.pos = cumsum(domain_length) - 0.5*domain_length) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=MIRNA, fill = MIRNA_Feature)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="summary", aes(y=domain_length), fun.y=sum) +
  geom_label(aes(label=expr, y=y.pos), size=2.7, 
             label.padding=unit(0.15, "lines"), show.legend=FALSE) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]