# ggplot2 labels not properly being centered

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made a chart with the following data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

mydf <- tibble(type = c(rep(c(rep("TypeA", 4), rep("TypeB", 4)), 2)),
               Ratings = rep(c("Top", "Middle", "Low", "NA"), 4),
               Prop = c(0.62, 0.15, 0.15, 0, 0.32, 0.16, 0.47, 0, 0.38, 0.31, 0.31, 0, 0.16, 0.16, 0.63, 0.05),
               Question = c(rep("Question1", 8), rep("Question2", 8)))
mydf$Ratings <- factor(mydf$Ratings) %>% fct_inorder() %>% fct_rev()
```

And here's my code to make the chart:

```
mydf %>% filter(Prop > 0) %>% ggplot(aes(x = Question, y = Prop, fill = Ratings)) + 
geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") + 
geom_text(aes(label = percent(round(Prop,2))), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) + 
facet_grid(~ type) + scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) + 
guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

It produced the following chart. I specifically used `position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)` to center the labels halfway through the bars. It clearly doesn't look right for the labels for Question1. Is this a bug? Have I set my data up incorrectly?

[image]

Comment: You need to create another variable that defines the height for the label, see [here](https://www.getdatajoy.com/examples/r-plots/stacked-bar-graph) for more details.

Comment: As per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6645506/5221626), this is no longer needed for ggplot2 v2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `position="fill"` for `geom_bar`, but `position_stack` for `geom_text`. As a result, the top of the `geom_bar` stack is always 100%, but the top of the `geom_text` stack is whatever the sum of the values in that stack happens to be. The sums of the values for `TypeA` `Question1` and `TypeB` `Question1` are both less than 100%, so the height of the label stack is lower than the height of the bar stack.

For the label heights to match the bar heights, change to `position_fill` in `geom_text`. (Note, however, that since the percentages don't add up to 100% for two of the four bar stacks, using `position_fill()` is misleading if you don't also normalize the labels to add to 100% in each stack.)

I've also removed the last line reversing the legend so that the legend will be in the same color order as the bar sections:

```
mydf %>% filter(Prop > 0) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Question, y = Prop, fill = Ratings)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = percent(round(Prop,2))), position=position_fill(vjust = 0.5)) + 
  facet_grid(~ type) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

[image]