# ggplot_bar stacked showing the data values omitting values based on threshold

Tags: r, stack, position, geom-bar, geom-text

As a follow up question to this one: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644997/showing-data-values-on-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2/45569496#45569496)

Is it possible to exclude values when using the `position = position_stack()` in `geom_text()` ? For instance, something like: define the subset data within the geom_text and redefine the aes the `geom_text(data=subset(Data,Frequency<250), aes(x = Year, y = Frequency),size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))`. The above logic throws an error of uneval classes.

Answer (score 0):

Since label in `geom_text` is parsed automatically to text you can hard code it to empty string where one doesn't want to display the values.