# 100% Stacked Bar Chart Data Labels not a percentage

Tags: r, bar-chart, label, stacked-chart

I am trying to make a 100% stacked bar chart in R using ggplot2 and get data labels for the true count, not a percentage. When I try to do that I get tiny bars with just the labels way out on the other side of the graph. I can get a regular bar chart with the counts in the bars and I know there are many questions already on here with how to get the percentages, but I haven't found any answers like what I'm looking for. 
This is for work, but some mock data would be similar to:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "assessment User N
missingcomma Sara 5
notcapitolized Sara 2
noindent Sara 1
missingcomma Jason 1
notcapitolized Jason 3
noindent Jason 4
missingcomma Andre 3
notcapitolized Andre 1
noindenet Andre 2", header = TRUE)
```

With this code I can get the bar chart and data labels:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = assessment, y = N, fill = User)) + 
     geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
     geom_text(aes(label = N), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
     coord_flip()
```

Bar chart & labels:

[image]

And with this code I can get a 100% stacked chart with my labels in the middle of nowhere.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = assessment, y = N, fill = User)) + 
     geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill") + 
     geom_text(aes(label = N), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
     coord_flip()
```

100% Stacked Chart w/ crazy labels:

[image]

Please help, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to calculate the text positions by group, as in the "older versions of ggplot" part of Ramnath's answer here: [Showing data values on stacked bar chart in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644997/showing-data-values-on-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2).

The `ave()` function is, for each group in `assessment`:

1. Using `cumsum()` to calculate the total heights of the stacked bars if they **weren't** `position = "fill"`
2. Subtracting each count from that total, shifted by half its value
3. Normalizing them by the group's total count because the `position = "fill"` normalizes them to y-axis range [0, 1]

ggplot(dat) + 
    geom_col(aes(x = assessment, y = N, fill = User), position = "fill") +
    geom_text(aes(x = assessment, 
                  y = ave(dat$N, dat$assessment, 
                          FUN = function(x) (cumsum(x) - 0.5 * x) / sum(x)), 
                  label = N)) +
    coord_flip()

[image: ggplot]