# ggplot2 Stacked Bar Chart Data Labels are Backwards

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to create a stacked bar chart in ggplot2 with the data labels centered over the filled area that they relate to. The code I've tried has the labels in the reverse order that they should be in. here is a sample of code:

```
data_rep <- data.frame(Task.Number = c('5.004','5.004','5.01','5.01','5.04','5.04'),
               Within_SLA = rep(c('No','Yes'),3),
               Perc_SLA = c(4.8,95.2,1,99,9.6,90.4))

ggplot(data_rep, aes(x=Task.Number,y=Perc_SLA)) +
geom_bar(aes(fill=Within_SLA),stat="identity",position="stack") +
geom_text(aes(label=Perc_SLA), size = 3) + 
scale_fill_discrete(name = "Within SLA") + 
coord_flip()
```

This is what I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: How exactly would you like the data labels to be centered? It's difficult to understand your problem from your description.

Comment: Hi, The top bar for example would have the 90.4 in the center of the green and 9.6 in the red/pink area.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing data values on stacked bar chart in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644997/showing-data-values-on-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to set position to stack for the text labels as well.

```
ggplot(data_rep, aes(x=Task.Number,y=Perc_SLA, fill=Within_SLA)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack") +
  geom_text(aes(label=Perc_SLA), position =position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) + 
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Within SLA") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]