# reverse label ordering when passing variable in geom_bar(aes()) instead of ggplot(aes())

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following bar chart can be produced without problems:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

data <- tibble(Category = c("Baseball",
                            "Basketball",
                            "Basketball",
                            "Basketball",
                            "Football",
                            "Football",
                            "Hockey")) %>%
  group_by(Category) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(n = prop.table(n))

# displays correctly
ggplot(data, aes (x="", y = n, fill = Category)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(n, "%")),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

If, however, `fill = Category` is placed inside `aes` of `geom_bar`, then the labels of `geom_text` are displayed in reverse order.

```r
# labels are displayed in reverse order
ggplot(data, aes (x="", y = n)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Category), width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(n, "%")),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

This behavior can be prevented, either by: using `fct_rev`

```r
ggplot(data, aes (x="", y = n)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = fct_rev(Category)), width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(n, "%")),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Or by adding `fill = Category` in the `aes` of `geom_text`.

```r
ggplot(data, aes (x="", y = n)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Category), width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(fill = Category, label = paste(n, "%")),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fill
```

[image]

Although this yields a warning saying:

> Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fill

I do not understand:

1. why labels in `geom_text` are reversed when `fill` is placed in `geom_bar(aes)`; and
2. why this behavior can be prevented when adding `fill` (which is an unknown aesthetic) to `geom_text(aes)`.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47211534/296725

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure yet what exactly the issue is, but it is related to grouping. The reason that `fill` triggers this problem is that it sets up grouping, so when you don't provide the `fill` aesthetic in the main `ggplot()` call you don't get the groups right. One way to fix this is to provide explicit grouping in `geom_text()`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

data <- tibble(Category = c("Baseball",
                            "Basketball",
                            "Basketball",
                            "Basketball",
                            "Football",
                            "Football",
                            "Hockey")) %>%
  group_by(Category) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(n = prop.table(n))

ggplot(data, aes (x="", y = n)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Category), width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(n, "%"), group = Category),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Interesting. This might explain why providing `fill` to `geom_text(aes)` fixes the label order. Although it is considered as an unknown aesthetic for `geom_text`, it seems that it still sets up grouping. Is it worth reporting the whole issue on github, or do you consider this behavior as intended?

Comment: You can file an issue on github. Since I don't know what causes the behavior, I don't know whether it's as intended or not. One comment about the reprex: I suggest you manually create the final table rather than computing it. The table has only 4 rows and 2 columns, therefore it's going to be less code and easier to follow if it's not computed.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your issue:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
library(cowplot)

data <- tibble(Category = c("Baseball",
                            "Basketball",
                            "Basketball",
                            "Basketball",
                            "Football",
                            "Football",
                            "Hockey")) %>%
  group_by(Category) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(n = prop.table(n))

# displays correctly
p_good = ggplot(data, aes (x="", y = n, fill = Category)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(n, "%")),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))

# labels are displayed in reverse order
p_bad = ggplot(data, aes (x="", y = n)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Category), width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(n, "%")),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))

p = plot_grid(p_good, p_bad)
show(p)
```

[image]

I think the issue might be with your R installation, rather then the code.

Comment: The labels in your two charts *are* in fact in reverse order from each other.

Comment: @Donentolon: you pretty much reproduced my issue.