# How to draw a stacked bar chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use the code `dput(head(Refugees_demographics, 2))`

and here is the sample dataset below:

```
structure(list(Year = c(2006, 2007), `Female 0-4` = c(0, 3), 
    `Female 5-11` = c(0, 0), `Female 12-17` = c(140, 36), `Female 18-59` = c(1118, 
    519), `Female 60+` = c(121, 85), `F: Total` = c(1379, 643
    ), `Male 0-4` = c(0, 7), `Male 5-11` = c(6, 1), `Male 12-17` = c(152, 
    56), `Male 18-59` = c(1323, 870), `Male 60+` = c(595, 88), 
    `M: Total` = c(2076, 1022)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to get the following stacked bar chart. (like the photo)

[image]

The x-axis would be the year, and the y-axis would be the number of number of refugees. Each year would have two stacked bars. One for male and one for female. Within each bar, it's stacked by their age, i.e. female0-4, female 5-11...etc.

I tried to use the following code but it didn't work and I also have no idea how to group female and male by year.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(y = Refugees_demographics$`Female 0-4`,
               x = Refugees_demographics$Year, fill = product),
           data = Refugees_demographics, stat="identity")
```

If someone could help this, I will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please do not link to data: links go stale, and when they do this question becomes completely [unreproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It's generally better to (a) include a representative *sample* of your actual data; (b) randomly generate data and provide the code (with `set.seed`) to make it ourselves; or (c) use base-R datasets (e.g., `mtcars`, `iris`, `ggplot2::diamonds`, etc).

Comment: However, a search of StackOverflow for [`[r] [ggplot2] stack bar`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+%5Bggplot2%5D+stack+bar) should provide what you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/6644997/3358272 (holding out on closing this in case I'm wrong)

Comment: @r2evans, sorry about that. It's my first time to ask the question here. I changed the dataset to a sample dataset!

Comment: No worries, sodasky. Another thing that would be helpful is to read about [StackOverflow markdown formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), which can make it much easier to differentiate (visually) "conversation" from "`data/code`". In this case, just highlighting the `structure(...)` code and hitting <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd> worked. (Unfortunately, the `kbd` tags don't work on SO ... :-(

Answer (score 0):

You will need to transform your data prior to to creating the visual.  See the code below.  There are a number of things going on here that you will have to work through.  For example, I removed the total columns from your raw data, updated the year column, and updated the column names.

```
require(tidyverse)
require(lubridate)

df$Year <- year(as.Date(as.character(df$Year), "%Y"))

colnames(df) <- sub("\\.", "_", colnames(df))

df2 <- df %>%
  gather("Variable", "Total", 2:13) %>%
  separate(variable, c("Gender", "Age"), "_" ) %>%
  filter(age != ".Total")

df2$Age <- gsub("\\.", "-", df2$Age)

ggplot(df2, aes(Gender, Total, fill = Age)) + geom_col() + facet_grid(~Year)
```