# 'Missing value error/empty data when trying to add labels to a bar chart using geom_text with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, geom-text

I'm trying to add labels to my stacked barchart I made with ggplot2, but keep getting an odd error.

I made my table as such:

```
dd <- read.table(text = "ORIGIN ANIMAL SEX COUNT PR
             1 Canada Dog M 3 37.5
             2 Canada Dog F 5 62.5
             3 Canada Bunny M 3 75
             4 Canada Bunny F 1 25
             5 US Bunny M 9 90
             6 US Bunny F 1 10
             7 US Dog M 3 50
             8 US Dog F 3 50", sep = "", header = TRUE)
```

and made the figure:

```
p <-ggplot() + geom_bar(data = dd, aes(y = PR, x = ANIMAL, fill = SEX), 
  stat = "identity", position='stack') + 
  labs( y = "Proportion", x = "") +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid( ~ ORIGIN)
```

generating:

[image]

I'm trying to add COUNT labels to the data, similar to what was being done in this thread:

[Showing data values on stacked bar chart in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644997/showing-data-values-on-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2)

However, when I try to add the labels using:

```
p + geom_text(aes(labels = COUNT)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in if (empty(data)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I've tried explicitly stating all the Boolean arguments for geom_text, but R just ignores the unknown aesthetics.

Is anyone able to explain what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move common arguments to the main function, in particular, `data` and `x, y` aesthetics.

```
library(ggplot2)

p <-ggplot(data = dd, aes(y = PR, x = ANIMAL)) + 
             geom_col(aes(fill = SEX), position='stack') + 
  labs( y = "Proportion", x = "") +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid( ~ ORIGIN)

p + geom_text(aes(label = COUNT), position=position_stack(vjust=0.5), color="white")
```

Note that `geom_col` is equivalent to `geom_bar` with `stat="identity"`. You may also want to adjust the labels to the center of the stacked bars with `vjust` argument in `position_stack()`

[image: here]

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

I added 

    p + geom_text(aes(label = COUNT), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))

to get the formatting a bit neater, but thank you very much!