# Getting count instead of percentage in a grouped barplot with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, geom-bar

I found a script to make grouped barplots with ggplot.
But I want it to label each bar with the count instead of the percentage.

I am using this code right now:

```
ggplot(data = subset(data, geb_nat!="nat" & !is.na(geb_use)), 
       aes(x = geb_typ, group = geb_use)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..)), stat = "count") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(..prop..), y = ..prop.. ),             
            stat = "count", vjust = -.5) +
  labs(y = "Percent", fill="geb_typ") +
  facet_grid(~geb_use) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

and this is the result:

[image: Barplot]

I want to show the actual count on top of the bars not the percentage

Comment: Remove `scales::percent` and replace `..prop..` by `..count..`. You could further remove `stat="count"` because this is the default.

Comment: Thank you, works good for me !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing data values on stacked bar chart in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644997/showing-data-values-on-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2)