# R / ggplot2 / add total value(sum) above barplot with each value in fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, sum, bar-chart, addition

I want to add text of 'sum' value above the bar.

```
fac_report_field %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x = m, y = total, fill = field))+
 geom_bar(stat="identity")+
 scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1:12))+
 geom_text(aes(label = total), stat = "identity" , size = 1.5,
        position=position_stack(0.5))+
 facet_grid(.~y)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AlMA.png)

```
head(fac_report_field)
 # A tibble: 6 x 9
 # Groups:   y, m, ym [3]
  y         m ym     field    total  paid others opinion plc_ratio
 <fct> <dbl> <chr>  <fct>    <int> <int>  <int>   <int>     <dbl>
1 2016      1 201601 Non_life   499   143    355       1      28.7
2 2016      1 201601 Life       297   100    189       8      34.6
3 2016      2 201602 Non_life   433   128    305       0      29.6
4 2016      2 201602 Life       253    82    166       5      33.1
5 2016      3 201603 Non_life   609   176    433       0      28.9
6 2016      3 201603 Life       336    94    235       7      28.6
```

I made new data set 'fac_report_sum' as below

```
> head(fac_report_sum)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   y [1]
      y     m   Sum
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1  2016     1   796
2  2016     2   686
3  2016     3   945
4  2016     4   698
5  2016     5  1003
6  2016     6  1201
```

and add geom_text as below

```
fac_report_field %>%
ggplot(aes(x = m, y = total, fill = field))+
geom_bar(stat="identity")+
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1:12))+
geom_text(aes(label = total), stat = "identity" , size = 1.5,
      position=position_stack(0.5))+
geom_text(data = fac_report_sum, aes(label = sum, x = m, y = sum),
        vjust = -.25, size = 1.5)+
facet_grid(.~y)
```

however there is an error as below

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'field' not found
```

Please guide me how solve this problem.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing data values on stacked bar chart in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644997/showing-data-values-on-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing `inherit.aes = FALSE` in the second `geom_text`. Briefly, in your second `geom_text`, you are calling a new dataframe, however `ggplot` is still looking for the filling category `field` that you set in the first `aes` in this second dataframe. As it does not exist, it prints out an error.

If you used `inherit.aes = FALSE`, it will indicate to `ggplot` to not take in consideration of previous mapping arguments (NB: I subset `dfsum` to match the values of `m` in the first dataframe):

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df_report, aes(x = m, y = total, fill= field))+
  geom_col()+
  geom_text(aes(label = total),
            position=position_stack(0.5))+
  geom_text(inherit.aes = FALSE, data = subset(dfsum, m %in% 1:3), 
            aes(x = m, y = Sum, label = Sum), vjust = -0.25)+
  ylim(0,1000)
```

[image]

**Example Data**

df_report (equivalent to your `fac_report_field`):

```r
structure(list(Row = 1:6, y = c(2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L), m = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), ym = c(201601L, 201601L, 
201602L, 201602L, 201603L, 201603L), field = c("Non_life", "Life", 
"Non_life", "Life", "Non_life", "Life"), total = c(499L, 297L, 
433L, 253L, 609L, 336L), paid = c(143L, 100L, 128L, 82L, 176L, 
94L), others = c(355L, 189L, 305L, 166L, 433L, 235L), opinion = c(1L, 
8L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 7L), plc_ratio = c(28.7, 34.6, 29.6, 33.1, 28.9, 
28.6)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x55eb576ff5c0>)
```

dfsum (equivalent to your `fac_report_sum`):

```
structure(list(Row = 1:6, y = c(2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L), m = 1:6, Sum = c(796L, 686L, 945L, 698L, 1003L, 1201L
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x55eb576ff5c0>)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you provided `fac_report_field` or at least the `str()` of each `col()`

try

```
geom_text(aes(label = field), x = m, y = total)
```

?