# Adding count label to bar chart of proportional data in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a stacked bar chart of proportional data made with ggplot. I'd like to add the counts contributing to those proportions.

A subset of my data:

```
dput(sus_dev_data)
structure(list(individual_code = structure(c(9L, 10L, 7L, 6L, 
8L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 25L, 23L, 21L, 22L, 24L, 20L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 
29L, 30L, 26L, 28L, 15L, 13L, 14L, 12L, 11L), .Label = c("D5WMA-113", 
"D5WMA-133", "D5WMA-136", "D5WMA-137", "D5WMA-141", "D6UIC-109", 
"D6UIC-72", "D6UIC-87", "D6UIC-89", "D6UIC-97", "S6WMA-806", 
"S6WMA-810", "S6WMA-811", "S6WMA-815", "S6WMA-820", "S6WMA-859", 
"S6WMA-863", "S6WMA-866", "S6WMA-875", "S6WMA-876", "S7UIC-1202", 
"S7UIC-1215", "S7UIC-1250", "S7UIC-1252", "S7UIC-1253", "S7UIC-709", 
"S7UIC-724", "S7UIC-780", "S7UIC-827", "S7UIC-840"), class = "factor"), 
    population = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("UIC", "WMA"), class = "factor"), 
    time_point = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("3", "8", "12"), class = "factor"), 
    days_to_feeding = c(3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L), chill_number = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    days_to_pupation = c(135L, 142L, 143L, 155L, 149L, 159L, 
    153L, 171L, 9L, 67L, 53L, 49L, 72L, 67L, 55L, 64L, 60L, 122L, 
    53L, 51L, 49L, 53L, 50L, 56L, 44L, 47L, 60L)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

My current ggplot code:

```
(prop_plot <- ggplot(sus_dev_data, aes(x = time_point, fill = chill_number)) +
  Alex_Theme +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", color = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey90", "white")) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("3" = "13", "8" = "18",
                             "12" = "22")) +
  labs(y = 'Proportion pupated after 79 days', x = 'Weeks post-hatch')
)
```

[image]

Now I'd like to add the counts contributing to those proportions. All options that I've tried either pin the values at the top of the plot or I get errors. I've been following this similar thread ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644997/showing-data-values-on-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2](http://https:/stackoverflow.com/questions/6644997/showing-data-values-on-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2)), but none of those options are working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try to calculate the data before plotting

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(time_point) %>% 
  count(chill_number) %>% 
  mutate(perc = n/sum(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(time_point, perc, fill =chill_number)) + 
    geom_col(position = position_stack()) + 
    geom_text(aes(label = n), position = position_stack(vjust =0.5), size =12)
```

[image]

or try

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = time_point, y = (..count..)/sum(..count..), fill = chill_number)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  stat_count(geom = "text", aes(label = ..count..), position = position_stack(vjust =0.5))
```