# How to include geom_label for a column ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-col

Hi so I have some data which looks like this:

```
   `Marketing Variables`         LICENCE_STATUS count   pct val   
   <chr>                         <chr>          <lgl> <int> <chr> 
 1 RESIDENT_MARKETING_ALLOWED    ACTIVE         FALSE  7612 46.61%
 2 RESIDENT_MARKETING_ALLOWED    ACTIVE         TRUE   8720 53.39%
 3 RESIDENT_MARKETING_ALLOWED    CANCELLED      FALSE   418 52.05%
 4 RESIDENT_MARKETING_ALLOWED    CANCELLED      TRUE    385 47.95%
 5 RESIDENT_MARKETING_ALLOWED    EXPIRED        FALSE 78352 81.85%
 6 RESIDENT_MARKETING_ALLOWED    EXPIRED        TRUE  17373 18.15%
 7 THIRD_PARTY_MARKETING_ALLOWED ACTIVE         FALSE 10629 65.1% 
 8 THIRD_PARTY_MARKETING_ALLOWED ACTIVE         TRUE   5698 34.9% 
 9 THIRD_PARTY_MARKETING_ALLOWED CANCELLED      FALSE   571 70.93%
10 THIRD_PARTY_MARKETING_ALLOWED CANCELLED      TRUE    234 29.07%
11 THIRD_PARTY_MARKETING_ALLOWED EXPIRED        FALSE 85166 88.92%
12 THIRD_PARTY_MARKETING_ALLOWED EXPIRED        TRUE  10612 11.08%
```

And the goal is I want to make a faceted column chart with the code below:

```
ggplot(test) +
  geom_col(aes(x = `Marketing Variables`, y = pct, fill = count), position = "fill") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal()+
  facet_wrap(~LICENCE_STATUS)
```

The issue however is I want to add a `geom_label()` of the variable `val` to each bar. The val I wish to show is for the TRUE count for that variable.

As an example:

The first Column is:

- LICENCE_STATUS: **Active**
- Marking Variables: **THIRD_PARTY_MARKETING_ALLOWED**

Here we see at `count = TRUE`, a `val` of 34.9%. So I want the 34.9% to be 34.9% deep in the bar, or essentially where the blue meets the red.

[image: location of geom_label]

Notice, I do not want the val for FALSE to appear anywhere; and yes, only true and false are the options for `count` in the real data.

Here's the data:

```
structure(list(`Marketing Variables` = c("RESIDENT_MARKETING_ALLOWED", 
"RESIDENT_MARKETING_ALLOWED", "RESIDENT_MARKETING_ALLOWED", "RESIDENT_MARKETING_ALLOWED", 
"RESIDENT_MARKETING_ALLOWED", "RESIDENT_MARKETING_ALLOWED", "THIRD_PARTY_MARKETING_ALLOWED", 
"THIRD_PARTY_MARKETING_ALLOWED", "THIRD_PARTY_MARKETING_ALLOWED", 
"THIRD_PARTY_MARKETING_ALLOWED", "THIRD_PARTY_MARKETING_ALLOWED", 
"THIRD_PARTY_MARKETING_ALLOWED"), LICENCE_STATUS = c("ACTIVE", 
"ACTIVE", "CANCELLED", "CANCELLED", "EXPIRED", "EXPIRED", "ACTIVE", 
"ACTIVE", "CANCELLED", "CANCELLED", "EXPIRED", "EXPIRED"), count = c(FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE), pct = c(7612L, 8720L, 418L, 385L, 78352L, 17373L, 10629L, 
5698L, 571L, 234L, 85166L, 10612L), val = c("46.61%", "53.39%", 
"52.05%", "47.95%", "81.85%", "18.15%", "65.1%", "34.9%", "70.93%", 
"29.07%", "88.92%", "11.08%")), row.names = c(NA, -12L), groups = structure(list(
    `Marketing Variables` = c("RESIDENT_MARKETING_ALLOWED", "RESIDENT_MARKETING_ALLOWED", 
    "RESIDENT_MARKETING_ALLOWED", "THIRD_PARTY_MARKETING_ALLOWED", 
    "THIRD_PARTY_MARKETING_ALLOWED", "THIRD_PARTY_MARKETING_ALLOWED"
    ), LICENCE_STATUS = c("ACTIVE", "CANCELLED", "EXPIRED", "ACTIVE", 
    "CANCELLED", "EXPIRED"), .rows = structure(list(1:2, 3:4, 
        5:6, 7:8, 9:10, 11:12), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I am specifically looking for the solution with `geom_label()'

**EDIT** The reason I am unable to use the linked solution is I get the following error:

```
Error in layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomText,  : 
  object 'val' not found
```

This occurs when I add the following:

```
geom_text(label = val, y = pct, size = 2.5, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
```

Comment: Are the example data the same as you used for the plot? The values "IN_DISPUTE", "REVOKED" and "TRIAL_EXPIRED" don't appear in the example data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing data values on stacked bar chart in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644997/showing-data-values-on-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2)

Comment: @colebrookson the dput data is the actual data, the plot i show only shows three.

Comment: @divibisan, I am looking for the geom_label() solution specifically

Comment: @JohnThomas `geom_text` and `geom_label` are pretty much identical. The only difference is that label draws a rectangle behind the text. So the answers on the duplicate that use `geom_text` should work just as well with `geom_label`. Give them a try. If they don't work, edit your question to show what you did and why those answers are not satisfactory. That will help us narrow down the specifics of your problem

Comment: @divibisan added why this will not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve your desired result like so:

1. As for the bars set `position="fill"` in `geom_label` too.
2. To only add the `val` if `count=TRUE` use an `ifelse` which assigns an `NA` to `FALSE`.
3. To silence the warning about removed missing use `na.rm=TRUE`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(test, aes(x = pct, y = `Marketing Variables`, fill = count)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  geom_label(aes(label = ifelse(count, val, NA_character_)), position = "fill", na.rm = TRUE, show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_minimal() +
  facet_wrap(~LICENCE_STATUS)
```

[image]

Comment: this is good! what do u recommend about the cutoff on the right most plots?

Comment: Cut your the labels mapped on y to make more room for the plot. :D It that is not an option use `+ coord_cartesian(clip = "off")` to prevent the labels from be clipped off, reduce the font size and perhaps increase the spacing between the panels using `theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(...., "pt"))`