# Stacked barplot for a matrix with numbers as labels on the bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

I have a matrix which has 4 columns and 4 rows. But I am having a lot of troubles to put the numbers in the graph in an elegant way. Specifically, I want to have the numbers of the each part of the stacked bars to distinguish the percentages.

The matrix is this one, named as `tabl`.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3.89 | 4.97 | 8.56 | 7.17 |
| 35.67 | 42.73 | 51.68 | 50.09 |
| 48.30 | 43.48 | 34.95 | 38.24 |
| 12.14 | 8.82 | 4.81 | 4.50 |

And my current code to plot it is

```
nombres_comp <- c("Tac. \n Urb",
                  "Ven. \n Urb",
                  "Tac. \n Game",
                  "Ven. \n Game")

bp<-barplot(tabl,
        main = NULL,
        xlab = "(%)",
        ylab = NULL,
        axes = TRUE,
        horiz = TRUE,
        beside = FALSE,
        names.arg = nombres_comp,
        col = c("#487c82","#487c83", 
                "#81e0eb", "#b1ecf2")
        )
y <- tabl
text(bp+2,y,labels=as.character(y))
```

However, the output is putting the numbers in a strange place outside of the bars. I want them to be inside each place correctly identified in the barplot().

[image]

Also I would appreciate if someone beside solving this, could show me for completeness how to do this on ggplot2.

Comment: Here's how you'd do it in ggplot2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644997/showing-data-values-on-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2. There are many more examples if you search for "labeling stacked bar chart in ggplto2". I posted an answer for your base solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tabl <- as.matrix(read.table(text = "3.89   4.97    8.56    7.17
                                     35.67  42.73   51.68   50.09
                                     48.30  43.48   34.95   38.24
                                     12.14  8.82    4.81    4.50", header = F))

nombres_comp <- c("Tac. \n Urb", "Ven. \n Urb",
                  "Tac. \n Game", "Ven. \n Game")

bp<-barplot(tabl,
            main = NULL, xlab = "(%)", ylab = NULL,
            axes = TRUE, horiz = TRUE, beside = FALSE,
            names.arg = nombres_comp,
            col = c("#487c82", "#487c83", "#81e0eb", "#b1ecf2"))

y <- apply(tabl/2 + rbind(rep(0, ncol(tabl)) , 
                          head(apply(tabl, 2, cumsum), -1)), 
           1, as.numeric)

l <- as.character(apply(tabl, 1, as.character))

text(bp,x = y , labels= l)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>